# Algebraic properties of graph of chess pieces

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, chess

For the purpose of this question, a *chess piece* is the King, Queen, Rook, Bishop or Knight of the game of chess. To a chess piece is attached a graph which represents the legal moves it can make on an empty chess board. Except for the bishop, the graph attached to a chess piece has 64 vertices, while the bishop's graph has 32 vertices.

These graphs satisfy a number of interesting mathematical properties from the point of view of graph theory.

- Only the rook's graph is regular, and the rook's graph is even strongly regular (a fact well-known to chess player with no knowledge of mathematics).
- The knight's graph is bipartite.
- The king's, rook's, queen's and bishop's graph are hamiltonian (and after Euler, it is very well-known though to me non-obvious *a priori* that the knight's graphs is hamiltonian).

Less obvious properties have of course been devised by graph theorists.

Recently, I asked myself (with no other purpose than leisure) if these graphs were known to satisfy interesting algebraic properties.

A quick computation based on its strong regularity or on the observation that it is the cartesian product of two copies of the complete graph $K_8$ show that spectrum of the rook's graph is $\{14^{(1)},6^{(14)},-2^{(49)}\}$ (in particular, it is an integral graph).

> Are there any other remarkable algebraic properties of the graphs of chess pieces, either of their spectra or of their group of automorphisms?

Comment: My guess is that you will get nicer properties for a toroidal chessboard.

Comment: Or a Klein bottle! At the risk of getting slightly off-topic, I can't resist mentioning some [chess puzzles on a Klein bottle](http://timothychow.net/kleines.pdf) that I once composed.

Answer (score 12):

The clique complex of the complement of the rook's graph is sometimes called a *chessboard complex*.  It has some remarkable algebraic properties.  For example, its Laplacian eigenvalues are all nonnegative integers. This is a rare property, shared by matroid complexes but very few other "naturally occurring" simplicial complexes. See for example Michelle Wachs's paper [Topology of matching, chessboard, and general bounded degree graph complexes](http://www.math.miami.edu/~wachs/papers/tmc.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Great answer! The OP is encouraged to see in particular the Friedman-Hanlon Theorem [Thm 3.2 in Wachs's survey]. It relates the reduced cohomology of $m \times n$ chessboard complexes to irreducible representations of products of symmetric groups $S_m \times S_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says the [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) is "studied in algebraic graph theory".  So here's an answer involving the chromatic polynomial of the rook's graph.

The rook's graph is $K_8 \Box K_8$, i.e., the Cartesian product of $K_8$ and $K_8$.

The chromatic polynomial $P(K_8 \Box K_8;n)$ of the rook's graph is the number of $8 \times 8$ generalized Latin squares, where we can use $n$ symbols (without repeated symbols in any row or column).  In particular, evaluating it at its chromatic number...

$$P(K_8 \Box K_8;8) = \text{number of Latin squares of order $8$}.$$